# Application stops while loading data

Tags: xcode4

Hi Guys
I am getting the build time error as: Misconfigured Property. Command /Developer/usr/bin/momc failed with exit code 6

:EDIT:
Done with MOMC error.

Application build & run successful; however stops while loading data:

```
2011-05-02 21:47:40.779 ReportViewer[3448:5d03] *** copyDb2TargetDir is successful ***
2011-05-02 21:47:41.000 ReportViewer[3448:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray  insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x016575a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x017ab313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x016511b1 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 225
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0164c604 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 68
4   CoreData                            0x00da9b0e +[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:] + 350
5   ReportViewer                        0x0000796f -[ReportStorage managedObjectModel] + 115
6   ReportViewer                        0x00007ad9 -[ReportStorage persistentStoreCoordinator] + 307
7   ReportViewer                        0x0000785d -[ReportStorage managedObjectContext] + 85
8   ReportViewer                        0x0000351d -[ReportStorage init] + 85
9   ReportViewer                        0x00002da4 -[ReportDataManager init] + 137
10  ReportViewer                        0x00002c18 +[ReportDataManager sharedManager] + 88
11  ReportViewer                        0x00009c8c -[FlipViewController viewDidLoad] + 327
12  UIKit                               0x003ad089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
13  ReportViewer                        0x0001ba77 -[StartFakeViewController dbMoveComplete] + 518
14  Foundation                          0x0007c94e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
15  CoreFoundation                      0x016388ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0159688b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
17  CoreFoundation                      0x01595d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
18  CoreFoundation                      0x01595840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
19  CoreFoundation                      0x01595761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
20  GraphicsServices                    0x01f141c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
21  GraphicsServices                    0x01f14289 GSEventRun + 115
22  UIKit                               0x0030bc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
23  ReportViewer                        0x00001c9c main + 102
24  ReportViewer                        0x00001c2d start + 53
25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException' sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
kill
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0
```